# Indexing "large" (>40Mb) documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I am trying to add a document of 43Mb into an index in Elasticsearch. I use the bulk API in python. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
from elasticsearch import helpers
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

document = <read a 43Mb json file, with two fields>
action = [
    {
        "_index":"test_index",
        "_type":"test_type",
        "_id": 1
    }
]
action[0]["_source"]=document

es = Elasticsearch(hosts=<HOST>:9200, timeout = 30)
helpers.bulk(es, action)
```

This code always times out. I have also tried with different timeout values. Am I missing something here?

Comment: When you open the URL for elasticsearch http://hostname:9200 , do you see a JSON response?

Comment: Can you check by making the timeout argument value as `None`

Comment: @kiran.koduru yes there is a response. Elastic is up and running. The same code above works with action[0]["_source"] = {"field1" : "value1"}

Comment: Please don't pass the `_id` field. Consider it like a PRIMARY KEY in other relational databases. It might fail if you reinsert it.

Comment: What analyser are you using against the data? if you're using ngrams this will be slow - you may need to switch to another parser.  How far away from the Elasticsearch server are you - are there any firewalls that may be blocking connectivity?  As a first step you should increase your timeout - workout how long it takes to do the insert and then look at ways to make this more efficient.

Comment: @BhargaviSri I've run the same code with timeout=None. It is still running after 10 minutes now.

Comment: @OllyCruickshank The Elastisearch server is on the same private network, there should not be firewall issues. I have set the analyzer to the 'noop' keyword analyzer described from the doc:
   PUT test_index
    {
        "settings" : {
            "index" : {
                "number_of_shards" : 1, 
                "number_of_replicas" : 1 
            },
            "analysis" :{
              "analyzer" : "keyword"
            }
        }  
    }

The query crashes after 14 minutes. In fact the whole Elasticserach server crashed after 14 minutes (service failed)

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in your Elasticsearch server - what do the logs say?  Does it look like a memory / CPU / diskspace issue?

Comment: Actually 43MB is not quite a correct metric. Apart from the 500mb upper limit, you can only index 1,00,000 records at once. So could you check that in your code?